# Omit lvalue when using get property

Tags: c#, properties

I've got a builder that helps me build centrain strings. The builder contains methods for keywords and properties for special characters, ex.:

```
class MyBuilder
{
    private StringBuilder bld;
    public MyBuilder() { bld = new StringBuilder(); }
    public MyBuilder KeyWord_1(string param)
    {
        this.bld.Append("Some_Keyword ").Append(param);
        return this;
    }

    public MyBuilder C_()
    {
        this.bld.Append(',');
        return this;
    }

    public MyBuilder C
    {
        get { return this.C_(); }
    }
}
```

And then I use it like:

```
var bld = new MyBuilder();

bld.KeyWord_1("some value").C;
```

What obiviously throws an error:

```
error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

So I'm forced to use:

```
var bld = new MyBuilder();

bld.KeyWord_1("some value").C_();
```

Is it possible to use property like in invalid example or in similar way (like, just `C` - `bld.C` - without parentheses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```
bld.KeyWord_1("some value").C;
```

To:

```
bld = bld.KeyWord_1("some value").C;
```

Explanation: 
The reason for this is that you cannot just access property via getter and *do nothing* because it is not a valid statement (line of code). Your property returns instance of MyBuilder and you should use it somehow (assign to some field, pass it to method as parameter and so on).

> Is it possible to use property like in invalid example or in similar
>   way (like, just C - bld.C - without parentheses)?

I am afraid it's not because property `get` accessor can only be used to get value and this value must be used somehow...

What is possible to do however is to create list of properties like this :

```
class MyBuilder
{
    private StringBuilder bld;
    public MyBuilder() { bld = new StringBuilder(); }
    public MyBuilder KeyWord_1(string param)
    {
        this.bld.Append("Some_Keyword ").Append(param);
        return this;
    }

    public MyBuilder C
    {

        get { this.bld.Append(','); return this; }
    }

    public MyBuilder D
    {
        get { this.bld.Append(':'); return this; }
    }

    public MyBuilder E
    {
        get { this.bld.Append('-'); return this; }
    }

    public MyBuilder F
    {
        get { this.bld.Append('+'); return this; }
    }

    public MyBuilder G
    {
        get { this.bld.Append('-'); return this; }
    }
}
```

And call your properties in one line:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bld = new MyBuilder();

            bld = bld.KeyWord_1("some value").C.D.E.F.G;
        }
```